# Why can't I load resources which are appended to the bootstrap class loader search?

Tags: java, javaagents, bytecode-manipulation

When adding a jar to the bootstrap class loader via `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch`, I can't load any of it's resources via

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("org/example/ClassInBootstrapJar.class")
```

However, `ClassLoader#loadClass` works as expected:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("org.example.ClassInBootstrapJar")
```

The problem seems to be that jars which are added to the bootstrap classloader this way are not added to `java.lang.ClassLoader#getBootstrapClassPath`, so `java.lang.ClassLoader#getBootstrapResource` can't find resources in the added jar (referring to Java 8 here).

When adding the jar via a `Boot-Class-Path: my-bootstrap.jar` entry in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of a javaagent, `ClassLoader#getResource` also works as expected.

Why is the behavior of `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch` different here and are there ways to make `getResource` work with it?

Comment: I never thought about it before, but the behavior you describe would explain why the method has been named `appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch` rather than `appendToBootstrapClassPath`, i.e. it only works for class loading, not for resource lookup. That’s also matching the literal meaning of the documentation’s sentence: “*When the virtual machine's built-in class loader, known as the "bootstrap class loader", unsuccessfully searches for a class, the entries in the JAR file will be searched as well.*”, not saying anything about resource lookup.

Comment: Probably the answer is that it’s just the way it is. Still a bit confused about the why. I guess the only workaround is to use a Boot-Class-Path manifest entry.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into same issue other day. Looks like appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch() does not update the boot class path property (sun.boot.class.path), whereas BootClassLoader resource search is based on this property.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/70e3553d9d6e/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Launcher.java

Thus the lookup fails. To me it is defect